# Difficulty mounting NFS as a layer in Overlayfs - bash: Operation not supported

Tags: linux, permissions, nfs, tmpfs, overlayfs

**Synopsis**

I'm serving a NFS share from my local machine and, while mounting and accessing the share works as expected, when I attempt to reference the NFS as a lower directory in overlayfs, operations requiring exec/read/write permission from a subdirectory fail with *Operation not supported*

**Setup**

Here's how I setup the mounts locally

```
sudo mkdir -p tmpfs_dir
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=4096m tmpfs tmpfs_dir

mkdir -p tmpfs_dir/{lower,upper,work}
sudo mount -t nfs -o ro,nolock,noacl,vers=3,proto=tcp 127.0.0.1:/nfsshare tmpfs_dir/lower

mkdir -p overlay_dir
sudo mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=tmpfs_dir/lower,upperdir=tmpfs_dir/upper,workdir=tmpfs_dir/work none overlay_dir
```

Calling ls on the root of overlayfs - *Good*

```
ls -lah overlay_dir
total 108K
drwxr-xr-x  1 myuser   myuser   40 Feb 12 00:31 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 myuser   myuser   4.0K Feb 11 17:19 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root     4.0K Aug 20 16:07 bin
drwxr-xr-x  4 root     root     4.0K Aug 16 14:36 boot
drwxr-xr-x 20 root     root     4.0K Aug 20 15:57 dev
drwxr-xr-x 98 root     root     4.0K Sep 10 18:13 etc
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root     4.0K Aug  7  2019 home
...
```

Calling ls on a subdirectory of overlayfs - *Breaks*

```
ls -lah overlay_dir/bin
ls: cannot open directory 'overlay_dir/bin': Operation not supported
```

Calling ls on the root of NFS - *Good*

```
ls -lah tmpfs_dir/lower
total 108K
drwxr-xr-x  1 myuser   myuser   40 Feb 12 00:31 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 myuser   myuser   4.0K Feb 11 17:19 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root     4.0K Aug 20 16:07 bin
drwxr-xr-x  4 root     root     4.0K Aug 16 14:36 boot
drwxr-xr-x 20 root     root     4.0K Aug 20 15:57 dev
drwxr-xr-x 98 root     root     4.0K Sep 10 18:13 etc
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root     4.0K Aug  7  2019 home
...
```

Calling ls on a subdirectory of NFS - *Good*

```
ls -lah tmpfs_dir/lower/bin
total 16M
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Aug 20 16:07 .
drwxr-xr-x 26 root root 4.0K Feb  7 14:57 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 1.1M Jun  6  2019 bash
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 700K Mar 12  2018 btrfs
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    5 Mar 12  2018 btrfsck -> btrfs
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 368K Mar 12  2018 btrfs-debug-tree
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 364K Mar 12  2018 btrfs-find-root
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 388K Mar 12  2018 btrfs-image
...
```

Calling an executable from a subdirectory of overlayfs - *Breaks*

```
overlay_dir/bin/bash
bash: overlay_dir/bin/bash: Operation not supported
```

It appears accessing anything below the root directory from with overlayfs will show the **Operation not supported** error. I have discovered, however, that recursively calling [`chown`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) *fixes* the files in the overlay share, but (i) it seems like an unnecessary hack to retouch permissions post mount and (ii) it's a little cumbersome detecting the owner on the file as failing to do so (e.g. blindly running `sudo chown` on every subdirectory) will throw an error on instances where the owner is different

```
sudo chown -R root bin

ls -lah bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.1M Jun  6  2019 bin/bash

overlay_dir$ bin/bash -c "echo 'why does it work now?'"
why does it work now?
```

**tl;dr**

How do I properly mount NFS from within overlayfs, so I don't have to retouch permissions post-mount?

**Specs**

- Distribution `Ubuntu 18.04`
- Kernel `5.3.0-28-generic`
- mount version `libmount 2.31.1`
- NFS server serving v4 and v3

**Further considerations**

- [Read-only nfsroot with NFS v4 and overlayfs](https://blog.fai-project.org/posts/overlayfs/) is the closest I could find to a similar issue
- My current research has led me to believe serving NFS over an older linux kernel might work ~4.15, so I'll see if that helps.